# Django Model Field from OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, model

I have two models:

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
     foo = models.IntegerField(default=0)
class SecondModel(models.Model):
     bar = models.OneToOneField(FirstModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

How do I make a variable `baz` that is from `FirstModel.foo`?

I wish it was as easy as:

```
class SecondModel(models.Model):
     bar = models.OneToOneField(FirstModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
     baz = bar.foo
```

**Ultimate Goal:** To get `foo` from an instance of `SecondModel` like `second_model_instace.foo`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in the linking model for backward reference:

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
     foo = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class SecondModel(models.Model):
    bar = models.OneToOneField(
        FirstModel, 
        related_name='baz', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        primary_key=True
    )
```

Now you can access as `first_model_intance.baz` if the link exists else you will get `DoesNotExsist` exception. The [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) is:

> If you do not specify the related_name argument for the OneToOneField,
>   Django will use the lower-case name of the current model as default
>   value.

**Update:**
If you want to get `second_model_instace.foo`, you do not even need `related_name` (backward reference). It is forward reference, which is already explicit. First get the first_model (via OneToOne Field) and then its attribute `foo`, that is:

```
second_model_instance.bar.foo
```

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of this. I was not explicit with what I wanted. I am going to update the question. What I want is to be able to do: `second_model_instance.foo` to get foo.

Comment: @Tsangares I have updated the answer. Is that what you were looking for?